# Order Lists by CAR

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I need to be able to compare two cars of a list to sort them im LISP.

Lists '(e d) (a b)

I want to compare the cars (e and a). This works using eql. If they don't match, I want to order the lists alphabetically, so (a b) (e d).
I'm missing the part where I can see which character is 'bigger', so the check if e or a should come first. I've tried converting them to ascii codes, but that doesn't work for (car a). Using arithmetic operators such as '<' and '>' also doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to compare symbols or characters?  The snippets here show you are trying to compare symbols.  Symbols can be compared for equality and nothing else. Characters can be compared with `char=`, `char>` and, `char< ` which have the obvious meanings.

Comment: OP double post to Reddit: https://old.reddit.com/r/lisp/comments/uco9k0/compare_string/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`string>`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_stgeq_.htm) without `symbol-name`:

```
CL-USER 6 > (string> 'a 'b)
NIL

CL-USER 7 > (string< 'a 'b)
0
```

For the sake of completeness, here is how you should use it inside [`sort`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_sort_.htm) to achieve desired result (`sort` is destructive- modifies used sequence, so I also used [`copy-tree`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cp_tre.htm) to avoid that effect):

```
(let ((data '((e d) (a b))))
  (sort (copy-tree data)
        (lambda (x y) (string< (car x) (car y)))))

((A B) (E D))
```

Comment: Or `(sort (copy-tree data) #'string< :key #'car)`.

Answer (score 1):

A symbol is distinct from a string.

```
CL-USER> (symbol-name 'foo)
"FOO"
```

A string (a sequence of characters) can be compared in the manner you seem to be interested in.

```
CL-USER> (string> "FOO" "BOO")
0
CL-USER> (string< "FOO" "BOO")
NIL
```

As [@ad-absurdum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6879826/ad-absurdum) notes, `string>` and `string<` can also be used with string designators, including symbols. While convenient, this muddies the water a bit, as the comparison is based on treatment of each symbol as the string corresponding to the symbol name.

Comment: The string comparison functions such as [`string<`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_stgeq_.htm) operate on [string designators](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_s.htm#string_designator), and symbols happen to be one type of string designator.